# Map of objects and change attribute from one object

Tags: c++, pointers

I have such a problem, I would like to replace the attribute `blocks.find(selfroot)->second.setRoot(otheroot);` ie. set a new attribute of type T in the block object using method SetRoot(otherroot).

I don't know if there is a problem with reference to this block object from the map. Where is the problem?

Here is my code:

Block.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Block.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
Block<T>::Block(T id, string sequence){
        this->id = id;
        this->sequence = sequence;
        this->component = {id};
        this->toroot = id;
}


template <typename T>
std::set<T> getUnion(const std::set<T>& a, const std::set<T>& b)
{
    std::set<T> result = a;
    result.insert(b.begin(), b.end());
    return result;
}

template <class T>
T Block<T>::find(map<T, Block<T>> &blocks){
    T rootid = this->id;
    if(this->toroot != rootid){
        rootid = blocks.find(this->toroot)->second.find(blocks);
        this->toroot = rootid;

    }

    return rootid;

}
template <class T>
void Block<T>::setRoot(T id){
    toroot = id;
    cout << toroot;
}

template <class T>
void Block<T>::unionto(Block other, map<T, Block<T>> &blocks, int reverse, int flank){
    T selfroot = this->find(blocks);
    T otheroot = other.find(blocks);
    blocks.find(selfroot)->second.setRoot(otheroot);

}
```

Block.h

```
#ifndef BLOCK_H
#define BLOCK_H

#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Block {

private:
    string sequence;
public:
    T id;
    int shift = 0;
    int reorder_shift = 0;
    int orient = 1;
    T toroot;
    map<int, int> flanks = {{-1, 0}, {1,0}};
    set<T> component = {};
    Block(T id, string sequence);
    T find(map<T, Block<T>> &blocks);
    void unionto(Block other, map<T, Block<T>> &blocks, int reverse, int flank);
    void setRoot(T id);
};


#endif
```

main.cpp

```
int main(){
    //initialize block
    Block<int> block1(1, "actg");
    Block<int> block2(2, "actg");
    Block<int> block3(3, "actg");
    map<int, Block<int>> blocks = {{1, block1}, {2, block2}, {3, block3}};
    block3.unionto(block2, blocks, 1, 1);
    cout << block3.toroot;  // should be 3 not 2
}
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253212/discussion-on-question-by-martin-inf1n1ty-map-of-objects-and-change-attribute-fr); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the `map<...> blocks` stores copies of `block1`-`block3`.
You can check that by printing out addresses of them:

```cpp
cout << &block1 << endl << &(blocks.find(1)->second) << endl;
```

In my environment, this gives

```
0x7fffdcf02930 <-- &block1
0x55c74d86cff8 <-- &(blocks.find(1)->second)
```

If you want your changes to propagate to the original objects, you'd need to store references/pointers in the map.

```cpp
map<int, Block<int>> blocks;
```

becomes

```cpp
#include <memory>
map<int, shared_ptr<Block<int>>> blocks;
```

Here is the code with the updates. I decided to use `std::shared_ptr` as you won't have to worry about memory management and object lifetimes. Code I haven't posted does not need an update.

```cpp
// block.h
...
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Block {
private:
    string sequence;
public:
    T id;
    T toroot;
    set<T> component = {};
    Block(T id, string sequence);
    T find(map<T, shared_ptr<Block<T>>> &blocks);
    void unionto(Block other, map<T, shared_ptr<Block<T>>> &blocks, int reverse, int flank);
    void setRoot(T id);
};
```

```cpp
// block.cpp
...
template <class T>
T Block<T>::find(map<T, shared_ptr<Block<T>>> &blocks){
    T rootid = this->id;
    if(this->toroot != rootid){
        rootid = blocks.find(this->toroot)->second->find(blocks);
        this->toroot = rootid;
    }
    return rootid;
}

template <class T>
void Block<T>::unionto(Block other, map<T, shared_ptr<Block<T>>> &blocks, int reverse, int flank){
    T selfroot = this->find(blocks);
    T otheroot = other.find(blocks);
    blocks.find(selfroot)->second->setRoot(otheroot);
}
```

```cpp
// main.c
...
int main()
{
    //initialize block
    shared_ptr<Block<int>> block1 = make_shared<Block<int>>(1, "actg");
    shared_ptr<Block<int>> block2 = make_shared<Block<int>>(2, "actg");
    shared_ptr<Block<int>> block3 = make_shared<Block<int>>(3, "actg");
    map<int, shared_ptr<Block<int>>> blocks = {{1, block1}, {2, block2}, {3, block3}};
    cout << block1 << endl << blocks.find(1)->second << endl;
    block3->unionto(*block2, blocks, 1, 1);
    //cout << block3.toroot << endl;
    assert(block3->toroot == 2);
}
```